# Copiar varias tablas con mismo prefijo

Tags: sql, sql-server

necesito pedirles consejo.
Tengo una base con mas de 100 tablas, de las cuales varias tienen un prefijo que las asemeja, como ejemplo 'TBS01_nombretabla', 'TBS01_nombretabla2', 'TBS01_nombretabla3' y asi sucesivamente... El asunto es que necesito copiar todas estas tablas con prefijo incial 'TBS01_' a otra base, y hacer esta misma operacion, para otras bases mas con el mismo caso, ya que trate de realizarlo con Select Into, pero tendria que hacer una query enorme para mas de 50 tablas por base.

Espero se entienda y ojala puedan ayudarme.

Comment: La base de datos destino, esta en la misma instancia de SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente script construye y ejecuta de manera dinámica una sentencia `select/into` para cada tabla que cumpla con el patrón de búsqueda, en una base de datos llamada `copia`.

Debes ajustar el nombre de la base de datos de destino.

```
declare @tableName sysname;
declare @sSQL nvarchar(max);

declare cTablas cursor for
select name
  from sys.tables
 where name like 'TBS01%';

open cTablas;

fetch next from cTablas into @tableName;

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
  print 'Trasladando ' + @tableName;
  set @sSQL = 'select * into [copia].dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' from ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName);
  exec sp_executesql @sSQL;
  fetch next from cTablas into @tableName;
end;

close cTablas;
deallocate cTablas;
```

Debes tener en cuenta que este *script* replicará los datos, pero no otros objetos, tales como índices, llaves foráneas y otros *constraints* que puedan estar definidos en las tablas.

Las tablas deben no existir en la base de datos destino.

Si las tablas ya existen y tienen la misma estructura, entonces, este script hará el trabajo:

```
declare @tableName sysname;
declare @sSQL nvarchar(max);

declare cTablas cursor for
select name
  from sys.tables
 where name like 'TBS01%';

open cTablas;

fetch next from cTablas into @tableName;

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
  print 'Trasladando ' + @tableName;
  set @sSQL = 'insert into [copia].dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' select *  from ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName);
  exec sp_executesql @sSQL;
  fetch next from cTablas into @tableName;
end;

close cTablas;
deallocate cTablas;
```

El script no toma en cuenta relaciones jerárquicas que puedan haber entre las tablas, ya que va ejecutando de manera secuencial según se encuentra la información en el diccionario de datos.

Por lo mismo, si hay *constraints*, por ejemplo, llaves foráneas, es mejor desactivarlas antes de iniciar y activarlas al finalizar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvio el script que mencionas, te pasaste!

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Por favor lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Un saludo.

Comment: Si estimado, ya hice esos pasos para tu respuesta, de nuevo se agradece mucho

Comment: Creo que no, ya que mi respuesta sigue sin votos y sin ser aceptada, pero no hay problema, tampoco es obligatorio, en realidad, como dije antes, me alegra ser de ayuda. Un saludo y que estés muy bien. ;)

Comment: De pura curiosidad fuí a ver, y veo que has recibido buenas respuestas en tus otras preguntas, pero tampoco has votado a favor ni has aceptado ninguna. Lo comento, por si se te ha pasado por alto. Si no sabes como hacerlo, lee [como funciona la aceptación de respuestas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/21). Un saludo.

Comment: Si estimado, he votado por las preguntas que me han servido, pero al hacerlo me aparece este mensaje "¡Gracias por tu comentario! Los votos emitidos por quienes tienen menos de 15 de reputación se registran, pero no cambian la puntuación que se muestra públicamente."

Comment: Comprendo, considero que es importante marcar respuestas como aceptadas, pues eso permite a visitantes futuros saber cual fue la respuesta que ayudó al AP a resolver su problema. No es obligatorio votar ni aceptar, pero si ayuda a construir un sitio que sea de ayuda para personas en el futuro. Un saludo.

Comment: Cierto, de hecho ahora el sistema me dejo marcar una respuesta como aceptada, pero aun no puedo votar hasta llegar a los 15 de reputacion. Igual agradecerte por el tiempo y consejos, ya que gracias a esta comunidad he podido resolver problemas y aprender mas. Saludos.